# Issue with using foreach

Tags: r, server, batch-processing, parallel-foreach

I have a question regarding doing parallel simulation using foreach and I really appreciate to your help in advance as I have spent hours and hours and I keep getting errors.

I'm using foreach() for a simulation study where in each iteration I run a function that that function itself has some "regular" loops. When I run it sequentially, it works perfectly fine. On a linux server, when I run it using foreach in parallel inside R, it works fine but as soon as I run it in the batch mode using "nohup R CMD BATCH" command, it starts returning errors. I set the seed numbers manually for each simulation and it means that regardless of running them parallel inside R, parallel in the batch mode, and sequential inside R, my codes basically are run on the same simulated data so that if one way does not produce any error, others should not lead to error either but strangely, it's not the case. Has anyone had the same challenge?

I've spent hours and hours, putting exception handling but nothing happened.

Here is my code:

```
 dataSim <- function(seedNum, n, mi, beta0FE, beta1, beta0RE){

 # Setting the seed number:
 set.seed(seedNum)

 # Generating covariates:
 x <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

 # Generating Y:
 data <- data.frame(id = rep(1:n, each = mi), x = rep(x, each = mi),     
                    beta0_RE = rep(beta0RE, each = mi))
 etaTmp <- data$beta0_RE + beta0FE + beta1*data$x
 piTmp <- exp(etaTmp)/(1 + exp(etaTmp))
 data$Y <- sapply(piTmp, rbinom, n = 1, size = 1)  
 return(data)
}

# Data Simulation Parameters:
n <- 100
mi <- 30
beta0FE <- 0.3
beta1 <- 1
beta0RE <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)

# Simulation Parameters:
nSim <- 10000
nIter <- 4000

LME_Freq_Fun <- function(data){
fit.LME <- try(glmmPQL(Y ~ x, random = ~ 1 | id, 
               family = binomial, data = data))
print(class(fit.LME)[1])
if (class(fit.LME)[1] == "try-error"){
  return(list(coef.FE.LME = rep(NA, 3),
            coef.RE.LME = rep(NA, n)))
}else{
  return(list(coef.FE.LME = fit.LME$coefficients$fixed,
            coef.RE.LME = fit.LME$coefficients$random$id))
 }
}

LME_Freq_RSLT <- foreach (i = 1:nSim) %dopar%{
 print(paste("i=", i))
 print("-------")
 data <- dataSim(i, n, mi, beta0FE, beta1, beta0RE)
 LME_Freq_Fun(data)
}

  # Extracting elements from foreach:
  Coef.Fixed.LME <- t(sapply(1:nSim ,function (i) 
                                     return(LME_Freq_RSLT[[i]][[1]] )))
  Coef.Rand.LME <- t(sapply(1:nSim ,function (i) 
                                     return(LME_Freq_RSLT[[i]][[2]] )))
```

With no "try", I keep getting:
     task 3527 failed - "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

With try, my Coef.Fixed.LME becomes very strange with all elements "numeric.2" !

Comment: can you give us sample code + data?

Comment: @Alex, Hi Alex, just added the code.

Comment: and what error do you get?

Comment: does it work if you do not use `nohup`?

Comment: @Alex, I added the errors I got to the bottom of the question. I just tried without nohup and I get the same error.

Comment: Is 10000 the smallest number of sims you need to run to reliably reproduce the error? Is there a particular sim number that breaks things?

Comment: @MrFlick, I did run it for 300 before and worked fine. I wanted to run it with a big number so that I minimize sampling error. Would you think that is the issue as I collect outputs (all 10000) in a list ?

Comment: Well, getting "numeric.2" doesn't seem like an error. It seems like you just have a nested list. If it ran for 300, then there must be a "magic" number where `glmmPQL` is failing or returning something different. Since you are setting the seed, you should be able to find the bad iteration when you do ` foreach (i = 1:nSim)` you don't always have to start at 1. It would help if you could make the reproducible example as *minimal* as possible in terms of compute time to reproduce.

Comment: @MrFlick, it's so strange that I when I use the seed number that caused the problem in the batch mode and fit for just that seed number, the model works perfectly fine.

Comment: @MrFlick, I just simply open R on the server and ran with 10000 and 60 CPUs and it worked fine. Don't know what happens in the batch mode !

Comment: @MrFlick, funny that it works fine with 1,000 iterations !

Comment: Some thoughts, somewhat random: is there anything on the guilty server that would be preventing background processes? IOW, is it perhaps the fact that *a job is running in the background more than x minutes*? (I know that one of my servers -- that I don't control -- doesn't allow long-running processes that aren't approved.) Are you using the same 32/64-bit architecture when running it interactively? If you randomize the order within `foreach` (perhaps `sample(1:nSim)`, does it change when the error occurs?